# How to render flash messages when remote true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a time logger controller method that calls from my view, called `_embed_menu.html.erb`

```
<%= link_to l(:start_time_logger) + ' #' + @issue.id.to_s + ' ',
   {:controller => '/time_loggers', :action => 'start', :issue_id => @issue.id},
    :class => 'icon icon-start',
    :"data-replace" => '#time-logger-menu',
    :remote => true
%>
```

The part of 'start' method, where I shown an error:

```
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js{ flash[:error] = l(:start_time_expired_error)}
      end
```

Now to the part of the rendering flash messages. `application_helper.rb`
Have `render_flash_messages` function.

```
  def render_flash_messages
    s = ''
    flash.each do |k,v|
      s << content_tag('div', v.html_safe, :class => "flash #{k}", :id => "flash_#{k}")
    end
    s.html_safe
  end
```

and that function called on `base.html.erb` template.

```
<%= render_flash_messages %>
```

So the result - I launch a start method and flash shown only after I reload the page. I also tried to redirect with the hope that after this redirect the error will show.

```
redirect_to controller: 'issues', format: 'js'
```

but no result.

Maybe I can trigger re-rendering of <%= render_flash_messages %>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just manually redirect to the page by window.location solution - here I just call issues index controller, but here can any link.

```
      flash[:error] = l(:start_time_expired_error)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js{ render js:"window.location='/issues/"+@issue.id.to_s+"'"}
      end
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you click a `remote: true` link is that Rails creates a request for `text/javascript` and then runs the resulting javascript in that page.

Usually a `js.erb` template contains some javascript that modifies the document:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @user) %>").appendTo("#users");
```

So if you want to alter the flash messages on the page you need to target the wrapping element and append it:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render_flash_messages) %>").appendTo("#flashes");
```

This assumes you have a wrapping element around the flash messages. Otherwise just add one to the layout.

```
<div id="flashes">
  <%= render_flash_messages %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flash.now[:error]` if you need to use the flash message on the same request.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-now
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#flash-now

Answer (score 0):

replace flash to `flash.now`.
for example,

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js{ flash.now[:error] = l(:start_time_expired_error)}
end
```

and in js.erb file re-render the partial where you want to update.